# Email file and folder list with size?

Tags: linux, debian, python, ls

I am trying to get a list of all files and folders with there sizes (upto 1st level, i.e. file and folder names with there sizes in current directory) emailed to me via an python script. I got the script working but using ls command as below only sends file-sizes and not folder sizes ?

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-1ahs', '/media/ExternalHd/myfolder'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Try the [`du`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/du.1.html) command instead of `ls`.

Comment: @PedroRomano did that but it lists folders only and not filesizes ? Maybe a hint towards du usage to list file and folder sizes would help...

Comment: Have you tried `du -s *`?

Comment: @PedroRomano using `du -sh /media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*` works on terminal, but using `p=subprocess.Popen(['du', '-sh', '/media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` in a python script shows error `du: cannot access /media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shell to expand "*", Popen's not going to it for you. So if you really want to use Popen, then

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', 'du', '-sh', '/media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```